# Access Js and css file in HttpModule

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpmodule

How to access Js and css file in HttpModule?

Comment: Can you give more details about what you need to do?

Comment: i have written  HttpModule to compress request size in gzip format.If i am running it in local all all js , cs and aspx files are getting compressed but if i am running it via IIS only .aspx file is getting compressed not js and css files.

Comment: On the IIS are the file types associated to the HTTP Module? Not all types are handled by ASP.NET/Module by default.

Comment: @Vaibhav , how to associate file types to the Http Module in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to associate the .css and .js extentions to the ASPNET_ISAPI.DLL otherwise IIS simply bypasses .net and processes and serves the file itself.

The method is different for various IIS versions but this should get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515343.aspx

*I have never actually built a proper HttpModule so I am just making an educated guess